# How to remove text cursor in rich:ComboBox in Richfaces?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using a combobox from richfaces. Check the following code

```
<rich:comboBox id="combo" value="#{thebean.selectedValue}" enableManualInput="false">
<f:selectItems value="#{thebean.listOfValues}" />
</rich:comboBox>
```

The items are displayed and is not editable. However, the text cursor appears when you click on the selected item. How to remove that ? It should be completely uneditable. No text cursor should appear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just use a normal dropdown, no combobox. Use `h:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: Could you explain that some more? The combo-box I've got is in a subform - and the control source is a meaningless ID key. I thought a combo box was necessary here, since the control source and the display value are different.

Come to think of it - I'm working in access; I don't know if that will make my situation totally unrelated.

Comment: @Olga: A combobox is an **editable** dropdown (a combination of `<input type="text">` and `<select>` achieved by a good shot of JavaScript/CSS). If you don't want to use an editable dropdown, then just don't use a combobox, but a normal dropdown (a `<select>` element as generated by `h:selectOneMenu`).